# How to send a ACK packet in Solaris10

Tags: sockets, tcp, solaris

For tcp connection, is there any way to send an ACK packet to the other side without other data (only the ack packet) in Solaris 10.

I know we can do that through TCP Keep alive option, but it's supported in Solaris 10.

Comment: Do you mean from an application, or are you referring just to the operation of the TCP stack?

Comment: In fact, I want to detect the tcp disconnection. Because Solaris 10 doesn't support Tcp keep alive option, I want to find another way to do so; maybe some function like get_socket_status(not a system call) will send an ack packet and return the connection status.

Comment: That wouldn't help. The keep alive ACK works because it is for the 'wrong' sequence number, so it provokes a reply with the correct current seqno. As per my answer there is no API whatsoever that will just send an ACK. And there is no API that will detect a disconnect other than reading and writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reliable way to detect disconnection is to build a null / ping / echo type message into your application level protocol, and have your application send those at regular intervals.  If it doesn't get a timely answer, it can assume the connection has been dropped.  Most protocols that are intended to involve long-lived connections include such a message (for example, IRC, IMAP and SSH all do).

(After all, even if you could send bare TCP ACK messages, the other end doesn't have to respond to them, since it has recieved no more data to ACK itself).

Comment: You last statement is dubious. The TCP/IP keepalive mechanism is based on the other end replying to dataless ack packets.

Comment: @jlliagre: [It appears that](http://bugs.opensolaris.org/view_bug.do?bug_id=4037313) such a response is actually optional.  Many TCPs send keepalives with one byte of duplicate payload, which do require a response.

Comment: The link you posted doesn't say the response is optional. On the opposite not replying was considered a bug. Moreover, that bug was fixed thirteen years ago and was referring to "Some older implementations" that were requiring that byte of duplicate payload. The RFC 1122 states they are bogus. Are you sure there are still active TCP/IP implementations demanding it ?

Comment: @jlliagre: It says: *"RFC 1122 Host requirement does not require a response to an out-of-order ACK. They say you MAY respond.  Indeed RFC 1127 (A perspective on the host requirement RFCs) states that the host requirement RFC makes no stand on the issue."*  The older implementations that were referred to were the ones that were *not* supplying the byte of duplicate payload on their own probes.

Comment: After looking at current Solaris tcp code, you are right. Keepalives probes sent by Solaris have one byte of duplicate payload. Keepalives probes received are ack'd whether they have that byte or not. It seems then that most implementations do not follow the RFC 1122 recommendation which is not to send that byte of data but prefer the alternative way. RFC1122 states: An implementation SHOULD send a keep-alive segment with no data; however, it MAY be configurable to send a keep-alive segment containing one garbage octet, for compatibility with       erroneous TCP implementations.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just receiving, the TCP stack will send plenty of ACKs without data all by itself. There's no way whatsoever to send an ACK of any kind from an application however.

Comment: However, note that with Solaris 11 Express, there is a way for the application to enable these ACKs to be sent by the TCP/IP layer.

Comment: Eh? You can't *stop* the TCP/IP layer from sending ACKs. Are you referring to TCP keepalive here?

Comment: Indeed. That's what the question is about after all, not regular acks.

Comment: IOW you mean to say there is a way to enable TCP keepalive in Solaris 11, right?

Answer (score 1):

You first posting states Solaris 10 is supporting TCP keep alives and later that it doesn't ...

Solaris supports setting tcp keepalive globally with the ndd command, eg:

```
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_keepalive_interval 120000
```

OpenSolaris and Solaris 11 Express support per socket keepalive settings.
You can enable it with SO_KEEPALIVE and tune it with TCP_KEEPALIVE_THRESHOLD and TCP_KEEPALIVE_ABORT_THRESHOLD.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2254/6n4iaov75/index.html